# Which author first referred to their own work as Grimdark?

Tags: history-of, fantasy-genre

This question does not apply to writers who have called their work grimdark *in retrospect.* Meaning, after the book had already come out. There are books that came out decades ago, before the term 'grimdark' was in use, that could still fall into that category. Instead I am referring to writers who have explicitly stated their work as grimdark, either as it was being written or before the book was released. Additionally, this includes any kind of author, whether they are established, indie, or self published.

Comment: For any type of work or just books?

Comment: I always thought 'grimdark' was pejorative.  Sort of like calling your own work 'smut.'

Comment: @Laurel Any written work.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet These kinds of terms can be taken multiple ways. Even if the originators of the term mean it to be pejorative, others who like the genre it describes might ignore their intentions and use it with genuine enthusiasm. Or maybe it becomes negative to some communities only later on. See also: "Space Opera" and even "The Big Bang".

Comment: Well the term "grimdark" comes from the tagline of Warhammer/Warhammer 40k series and was most likely "invented" on internet forums (in 1d4chan it is often used as a joke), but I don't think that we can pinpoint a moment when it was turned from a joke tern into an accepted name of the type of literature

Comment: Yes, I agree that would be a difficult moment to identify. But I think the question is trying to pin down something slightly less elusive.